# Cannot open pdf files in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, process.start

I am trying to make a help document popup with after clicking on a button in my App. I can see it appear in background processes in my task manager but never pop-up properly. If I manually open adobe and then click my button it works.

process.start("Help.pdf") used to work but does not anymore. Not sure what has changed. (Help file is still in the debug/release folder and same computer/apps)

I have also tried the direct file path, and also tried process.start on just adobe app, and then my help document. Still no joy, it just cannot open up adobe properly.

All other Apps seem to open fine with process.start

Webbrowser. solutions on the net seem outdated so I cannot find a solution via that route either.

Any clues?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Curious if this is your software or Windows. If you go to the run command on your desktop and type the path and filename, does it run your associated pdf viewer properly?

Comment: If you just double-click the file in Windows/File Explorer does it open?  It may be that you file has become corrupt somehow. What if you try `Process.Start` with a different file?

Comment: You might want to add the full path into the string parameter.

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide a full file path - e.g:

```
            Process.start("hello.txt") 'Error
            Process.Start("D:\Personal\hello.txt") 'works
```

Comment: As a comment to this - there's a good chance that you knowingly or unknowingly changed your build config and targeted a different folder to deploy your build to, that's probably why it can't see the file anymore without giving it the full path.